# Truncation of SQL Server Binary Data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Quick question.

In C# Code we have something like this:

```
string SQL =
                    string.Format(
                        "SELECT DATA FROM DERP_DOC WHERE THING_ID = '{0}'",
                            thingId);
            string Data = dataHandler.ExecuteScalar(SQL);
```

The "DATA" it's looking at looks something like this:

> 0x307832303230323032303230323032303230323032303332333033313330333133303332333933303338333033303330333033313230323032303230323032303230323032303230344334463534333132303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230344535373331333033303332323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303330333033303330333033303330333333353330333033303330333233303331333133333336333235303330333033313533333033303332353333303330333133333331333135313230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323034353538343134333534343135463535353334353532323033303334304430413230323032303230323032303230323032303230333233303331333133313332333233383330333833303330333033303331323032303230323032303230323032303230323034433446353433313230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323032303230323034453537333133303330333232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323041

However when I go to the database to look at the insert. It's getting something like this:

0x53797344656D2E422974655E6G

Any ideas?

edit: for reference the the insert statement that inserts the 'string" is of type "image" the same type that it's pulling that ginormous string from, so it shouldn't be any sql truncation datatype issues.

edit2: CODE AFTER SQL SELECT STATEMENT

```
        SQL =
            string.Format("INSERT INTO  WORK (DATE, TIME, LABEL, STATUS, " +
                          "ORDER, LNIT, SUBIT, ZONE, " +
                          "OPER, DATA, SEQ) " +
                          "VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', " +
                          "'{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}', '{9}', '{10}')",
date, time, "000", 0,
                        ordem, li, subli, zone,
                        strOp, Data, seq);
```

So Data is the value were getting it chopped off at.

Comment: Are you using SSMS to view the data? If so, this is normal, SSMS doesn't show all of the contents of binary fields.

Comment: Im just expanding out the column. So I can see the difference between where it's inserting and where it's pulling the original data from. And one is wayyyy shorter haha. Plus if I run just an update statement (to copy from one column to the other) it will get the correct data, it's just I think in the C# code it's messing up.

Comment: You need to show more code. We can't see where it gets truncated from what you posted so far.

Comment: Added the insert after. theirs nothing really before or after that's relevant to this unfortunatly.

Comment: You should consider using SqlParameter for adding values to your SQL queries to prevent SQL injections. Consider `SELECT * FROM Login WHERE UserName = \"{0}\" AND Password = \"{1}\"` - Imagine my username is this exact string: `" or 1=1 -- ` - Boom, instant access through the first user account. I know this may not be relevant to your situation but I figured I'd give some advice anyway.

Comment: That is helpful thanks. Im not the programmer for this code but I will pass along.

Answer (score 0):

It almost certainly is a data mismatch issue. Your ExecuteScalar function is returning a binary object, but then .NET is implicitly casting it into a string. Then, you're inserting the string into the SQL directly, and forcing SQL Server to cast it from a string back to a binary.

So, I'd make two recommendations:

1. Instead of storing `Data` into a string, store it into a byte array
   or some other byte structure.
2. Use parameters in your INSERT statement to strongly type the value of Data into a binary so that SQL Server doesn't do any conversion.

That should solve it.